# Why would one button cross over the other in Android RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I currently have two side-by-side buttons but it looks as if they are formatted how I would like them, but the left button overlaps and takes up the entire width and the right button does exactly what I want it to do. When pressed the left button looks as if both buttons are pressed because it is taking up the whole width.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/set_alarm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/time_picker"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/set_text"
        android:textSize="27sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/time_picker"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/cancel_alarm_text"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        android:onClick="cancelAlarm" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to add the: `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/set_alarm"` property like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/set_alarm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/time_picker"
        android:text="@string/set_text"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/time_picker"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/set_alarm"
    android:onClick="cancelAlarm"
    android:text="@string/cancel_alarm_text"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The reason they overlapping is because you have instructed them to be below a certain layout, but they are not aware of each other if you won't tell them and so the overlap one another.